# Dynamical variables in pentaho for Step - Table Input

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-design-studio

In my ktr, I need to create dynamic query for Step Table Input.
like -

```
Select ${SelectList} from ${Table}
```

The value of SelectList Table is coming from Step - Set Variables.

It is not working. Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assume that a `Set Variables` step will get its variables set at any time within the same transform. That is the nature of PDI's multi-threading. You need to be sure the variables are set before the `Table input` step begins. Generally this is done by putting the transform in a Job and setting the variables there, before the transform runs.

You can also pass parameters to the transform and read them into the transform with a `Get System Info` step referencing `Command line argument 1', etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think the **set variables** step  should not in the some transformation with any step using variables.

You should notice the information when creating the **set variables** step.